# Logs De-Obfuscation by Proguard

Tags: proguard

We know that proguard provides retrace function to deobfuscate strack trace. But does Proguard supports the functionality through which logs could be deobfuscated ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are generating mapping.txt file and then you can use retrace as explained at https://www.guardsquare.com/en/products/proguard/manual/retrace

however I don't think proguard offers anything for complete log file